# Delete repeating string in gvim

Tags: gvim

I have following text file

```
lbist_init_SAfull_pll_updt
lbist_init_SAfull_pll_updt
lbist_init_SAfull_pll_updt

lbist_init_FTMfull_pll_updt
lbist_init_FTMfull_pll_updt
lbist_init_FTMfull_pll_updt

lbist_init_TAM_SAfull_pll_updt
lbist_init_TAM_SAfull_pll_updt
lbist_init_TAM_SAfull_pll_updt

lbist_init_TAM_FTMfull_pll_updt
lbist_init_TAM_FTMfull_pll_updt
lbist_init_TAM_FTMfull_pll_updt
```

You can see there repeating patterns in this txt file.
How to get rid of all repeating patterns?

The output I need after the operation is

```
lbist_init_SAfull_pll_updt

lbist_init_FTMfull_pll_updt

lbist_init_TAM_SAfull_pll_updt

lbist_init_TAM_FTMfull_pll_updt
```

Comment: Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/351182/14467607) or `:%!uniq` if you don't want the lines sorted.

Answer (score 2):

If available, `:%!uniq` is the easiest answer.

If you don't mind sorting, [`:sort u`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/351182/14467607) is nice.

The long way uses only builtins:

```
:let lines = getline(1, '$')->uniq()
:%delete
:call setline(1, lines)
```